# jQuery Cropper, cropbox goes outside my canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, cropper

I'm using jQuery cropper to crop my images. Perfect plugin but I have 1 big issue...

When I set the dimensions to 1920/1080 my Cropbox goes outside my canvas. Is it possible to keep the cropbox inside the canvas and scale the image instead?

Here's my current code:

```
var cropImgData;
                $('#edit-image-' + $id).cropper({
                    // aspectRatio: $width / $height,
                    crop: function(data) {
                        cropImgData = data;
                    },
                    cropBoxMovable: false,
                    cropBoxResizable: false,
                    dragMode: 'move',
                    guides: false,
                    autoCropArea: 0.5,
                    built: function() {
                        // $('#edit-image-' + $id).cropper('setData', {"width": 5000, "height": 1000});
                        $('#edit-image-' + $id).cropper('setCropBoxData', {"width": 1920, "height": 1080})
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Why don´t you set the cropper width and height to canvas width and height or the other way?

Comment: In the future these will be dynamic dimensions. So if the designer sets the dimensions to 5000/3000 it will still be a problem I guess...

Comment: In that case you could change canvas dimentions

Comment: I could indeed, but a canvas with a width of 5000 px won't fit on the screen?

Comment: Is edit-image-' + $id the canvas? Are you setting max-width: 100% ?

Comment: Yes. Well, I tried to change the canvas dimensions but the problem is still there

Comment: Could you make a fiddle replicating the issue?

Comment: Ah! I think I know what you mean! Okay, now this works, but is it possible to define a min-width so the user can't go smaller than the given dimensions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134099/discussion-between-juvian-and-brecht-schepens).